# Can't replace new lines via tr or sed. : example: tail -10 /var/log/httpd/error_log | tr "\n" "----"

Tags: bash, replace, sed, tr

when i run this command..

```
tail -10 /var/log/httpd/error_log | tr "\n" "----"
```

tr replaces new lines with nothing rather than the indent of

```
----
```

i am using tr because perhaps it might be faster than sed.
but if there are no solutions.. i wouldn't mind using sed.

ultimately i am trying to replace new lines with

```
</br>
```

Comment: `tr` takes 2 sets of characters as arguments and replaces each occurence of the 1st set by the matching occurence on the 2nd set. For instance, `tr "abc" "xyz"` will replace a with x, b with y and c with z. Thus it wont be able to do the job in your case as you want to replace 1 character with several

Comment: Use this: `sed ':a; N; s/\n/<\/br>/g; $!ba;' yourfile`

Comment: `tail -10 /var/log/httpd/error_log | sed -e ':a; N; s/\n/\<\/br\>/'`

Comment: @sat, excellent answer. i would choose this as the answer but the answer has been marked as duplicate. the truth is it is not a duplicate question given the lack of knowledge that tr requires equal amount of characters for replacement

Comment: The fact is that the question cannot be answered using `tr`.  Since you mentioned that you can use `sed`, it already has answers.

Comment: @devnull, the fact that it can not be done via 'tr' becomes an apparent answer that benefits the internet.

Comment: If you search this site, you would find numerous posts mentioning what `tr` does.